# How to refrence a file path in a java build

Tags: java

I have my code and when i run it in intelji it display my image fine but when I build the jar file and run it then it dosen't know where it is

```
public static final Image WindowIcon = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
            .getImage("logo.jpg");
```

I tried to change the filepaths nothing works it only works when i put an absolute file path to my image thats outside of the jar file

Comment: Better to load your files/images as resources:
[Netbeans](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/78-loading-files-as-resources-in-java-with-netbeans)
[Eclipse](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/80-loading-files-as-resources-in-java-with-eclipse)

Comment: Search for previous answers. This issue has been asked thousand of times here.

Comment: With `MyClass.class.getResource("/path/to/logo.jpg")` where that path is the path the file has in the jar file. This gets you a URL; various constructors in swing accept it. Replace with `getResourceAsStream` for an `InputStream`. If you end up with a `File` instance, you lost - those __cannot__ refer to things in a jar.